# I'm start using Ruby Koans, but rake is aborting

Tags: ruby, rake

I think I don't have something installed correctly, because I am getting to following errors:

when I enter

```
rake gen
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gen' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I type `rake`, I get:

```
/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/bin/ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb

Thinking AboutAsserts
  test_assert_truth has damaged your karma.

You have not yet reached enlightenment ...
<false> is not true.

Please meditate on the following code:
/ruby_koans/koans/edgecase.rb:102:in `assert_failed?': uninitialized constant EdgeCase::Sensei::AssertionError (NameError)

      failure.is_a?(AssertionError)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    from ruby_koans/koans/edgecase.rb:112:in `report'
    from /ruby_koans/koans/edgecase.rb:265:in `block in <top (required)>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/bin/ruby ...]
/ruby_koans/koans/Rakefile:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've looked things up online, but am honestly new to all this so I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

[Ruby Koans](https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans) is an outdated -- absolutely *ancient* -- tutorial for Ruby that was created by [Jim Weirich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Weirich) at EdgeCase. Jim died in 2014 and although the material still exists [it has not been kept up to date](https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/commits/master/src) in any meaningful way.

Do not use Ruby Koans to learn Ruby. It was built around Ruby 1.8 which was [replaced by Ruby 1.9 in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Ruby#Ruby_1.9) and was [officially retired in 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Ruby#Ruby_1.8). You're using Ruby 3.2.1 which was released in 2023; 3.2.1 isn't going to work for Ruby Koans and attempting to install or learn with Ruby 1.8 or 1.9 is going to be a waste of time. Likewise, attempting to make it work with modern versions of Ruby is going to be a waste of time.

And although you didn't ask I'm going to give you my opinion as a Rubyist who learned Ruby during the time when Ruby Koans was created: it was never a good learning resource. It focuses heavily on having cutesy dialogue at the expense of being informative and educational. It is a relic from a bygone era and should be left in the past. Although the website is a fine memorial for its author its maintainers should make it clear that it is not a useful or viable way to learn Ruby in the modern day, nor is it representative of the Ruby language in the modern day.

There are plenty of other resources that you can use to learn Ruby in 2023, including:

- [Learn Ruby](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-ruby) by Codecademy
- [Ruby in Twenty Minutes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/) by ruby-lang
- [An Introduction to Ruby Programming](https://launchschool.com/books/ruby/read/introduction) by LaunchSchool
- [Paid Ruby courses](https://www.udemy.com/topic/ruby/) by Udemy
- [Paid Ruby courses](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=ruby) by Coursera
- [Paid Ruby courses](https://www.pluralsight.com/search?q=ruby) by PluralSight

There's also [*The Ruby Programming Language*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/) by David Flanagan & Yukihiro Matsumoto (creator of Ruby) if you prefer to get into the fundamentals of the language directly. While this book is also quite old (published in 2008) it is considered the *de facto* documentation for how the language works.

This isn't an exhaustive accounting of resources you can use to learn Ruby and I hope others will comment with their own recommendations (or recommendations against any of these) but they are a good start.